# Isotope has a broken layout on wordpress but works on another test page

Tags: wordpress, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a wordpress webpage, most of the page is built with worpress tools, but I made this page with custom code cause we couldn't find a better solution to filtering items without reloading the whole page.

https://latequebate.com/tienda/

Here's the webpage upload outside of wordpress

https://pruebaslate.000webhostapp.com/

The problem is that on wordpress it's broken on the first load, if I click on something or resize the windows it works fine.

Bare in mind this is a WIP and for now only the two first options do something on the second filter and only the first of the second one shows cards.

Comment: Whatever is calculating the starting position of those hijo inicio cgrafico papeleria div is likely doing it at the wrong time.  

On load, the second one looks like this:
<div class="hijo inicio cgrafico papeleria" style="position: absolute; left: 4.45313px; top: 0px;">

After a resize, it looks like this: 

<div class="hijo inicio cgrafico papeleria" style="position: absolute; left: 185px; top: 0px;">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why it wasn't working, autooptimize plug-in was doing some funny things, sometimes there's more to it than just clearing caches, disabling and enabling it solved the problem. Unchecking or checking some options also helps.

WP-Coder plug-in sometimes needs the JS in the HTML part instead of linking CDN options since that affects the order in which code is executed.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the answer but hard to format this in comments.

You have a JS error that's occurring on the Wordpress page that isn't occurring on the non-Wordpress page.  Don't know if it's related or not, I didn't dig that deep but the HTMLDocument.onReady sounds pretty suspicious.

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at k.fn.init.k.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
    at e (ce71c.js:94)
    at Object.logo (ce71c.js:94)
    at Object.init (ce71c.js:94)
    at HTMLDocument.onReady (ce71c.js:94)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that when inspecting, but I doubt I can edit that code, I wonder if there's a way to execute my custom code only the page has loaded, I find myself very confortable with HTML and CSS but I barely understand JS.